# Running a script during build of android app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I wanted to now if it's possible to run a .jar program or another script when building an android application or if somebody could guide me to an example.

I would want to sort my strings.xml file when I build a release.

probably what I forgot to say that I'm using gradle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own task of type [Exec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) and make the `assembleRelease` task depends on it:

```
task executeScript(type:Exec) {
    println 'Executing script...'
    commandLine './script.sh'
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    assembleRelease.dependsOn executeScript
}
```

Comment: thanx...i was probably to lazy to check the whole documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANT tools to build your application and use shell scripts to sort your strings.xml.

Comment: True, but i'm using gradle, i forgot to mention it in my opening post