# How can I reduce the size of xml assets when building my apk

Tags: android, gradle, build

In my app I use the assets directory to store some XML files (some are large).
In my design time I want the files to use indentation and also put some comments in it.
This is enlarging my xml files and can add up to a large size.

Is it possible to add a task to the gradle build to remove all indentation and comments for the xml files before packaging it in the apk? If so how?

This will not only shrink my apk, but will also assist at run time with the xml processing.

**EDIT**

The answer by **fhomovc** was correct, but was missing some part.
I will mark it as correct but if anyone else will need it, here are the details:

In general I need a task that will run the minify utility and it should look like:

```
task minifyAssets(type:Exec) {
    workingDir dirName // the directory of the merged assets under the build directory
    commandLine 'minify', '-r', '-o', '.', '.'
    doFirst {
        println 'minifyAssets...'
    }
}
```

This task should only be executed after the merged assets task is executed and before the package task is executed.

The main problem is that there should be a dedicated task for each variant, so I needed to do it dynamically:

First create the exec task and make it dependent on the merge task

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        // dynamically add minify task for specific variant
        def dirName = new File("app\\build\\intermediates\\merged_assets\\"  + variant.name + "\\out\\levels").getAbsolutePath()
        def minifyTaskName = "minifyAssets" + variant.name
        def mergeAssetsTaskName = "merge" + variant.name + "Assets"
        def myTask = tasks.register(minifyTaskName, Exec) {
            workingDir dirName
            // require that minify utility will be in the path. Download from https://github.com/tdewolff/minify/tree/master/cmd/minify
            commandLine 'minify', '-r', '-o', '.', '.'
            doFirst {
                println 'minifyAssets...' + workingDir
            }
        }
        // set the minify task dependant on the merge assets task
        myTask.get().dependsOn mergeAssetsTaskName
    }
```

Now we need to make the specific package task depend on the minify task:

```
// when the package task is added make it dependant on the minify task
tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
    if (theTask.name.startsWith("package") && (theTask.name.endsWith("Debug") || theTask.name.endsWith("Release"))) {
        def minifyTaskName = theTask.name.replace("package", "minifyAssets")
        theTask.dependsOn minifyTaskName
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried shrinking resources https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources? Otherwise you could just run a script with an xml minifyer like this one https://github.com/tdewolff/minify/tree/master/cmd/minify

Comment: Thank you for the reply. To my understanding the shrinking resources is about removing unused resources, so it is not relevant. Regarding the minify, it could be a solution, but I have no idea on how to integrate it in the build.gradle. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a custom script with an xml minifier.

- For the minifier: you can install [minify](https://github.com/tdewolff/minify/tree/master/cmd/minify) following the installation steps provided.
- For the script: you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033950/running-a-script-during-build-of-android-app#answer-25034787). Essentially your task would look something like this

  ```
  task executeScript(type:Exec) {
      println 'Minifying xmls...'
      //on linux
      commandLine 'minify -r -o ./ --match=\.xml ./values' // ./values should be the path to your resources directory
  }
  ```

Check the documentation to understand better how minify works. I haven't tested this solution myself, so it may need a few adjustments but you get the general idea. If you are using a Windows machine then the Script (`commandLine`) should be different, if I can find any examples online I'll add them.

Comment: This looks like the option I am looking for, however there are some issues: 1. I do not want to change the original files. From what I can see the build system copies the assets directory to app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\??? (a directory for each flavor), I want to change the files there. 2. When the task is executed, it is before the build copies the assets to that directory. 3. How do I get a reference to that directory (I do not want to use a hard codded directory). 4. When tried to run a none existing script, it did not fail the build (I need the build to stop if an error occur)

Comment: 1) You can use `-o` option to use a different output folder: `minify -o ./merged_assets/ ./values` or you can use `workingDir 'app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\'` inside the `executeScript`.  2) Check the `gradle.projectsEvaluated {assembleRelease.dependsOn executeScript}`option in the answer I linked. 3) You can add parameters in gradle.properties and load it in runtime. You can otherwise run it from console and add params there. 4) Check this question stackoverflow.com/questions/34234820 and `execResult` value. Good luck!

Comment: If I am using the executeScript as you describe, it will run it during the configuration phase (this in not what I need). I tried to change it and put the code inside a doLast block, but I am getting the error: Execution failed for task ':app:minifyAssets'.
> execCommand == null!

Comment: I am making it as correct since this is the way, but it is not complete. I updated the question with the complete solution. Thanks for your help.